# State of an Object with respect to unit testing

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, junit, nunit

I have the following class:

```
class UserValidator{

     // no constructor , default is fine. 

     void Validate(Request request, Response response){
        // some validation logic on request
        // if fails, add the message to response.
     }

}
```

Similarly I can do the same as follows:

```
class UserValidator{

     private Request request;
     private Response response;

     UserValidator(Request _request, Response _response)
     {
         request = _request;
         response = _response;
     }

     void Validate(){
        // some validation logic for request
        // if fails, add the message to response.
     }

}
```

For Testing which one is more preferable? Can i say that the second UserValidator class has a state and thus easier to test, whereas first one doesnt have a state and harder to test? Matter of the fact the first one can be a static class as well, which can not be passed to other methods, but if called statically it doest work.

Which one is better in terms of testability? which one contains state? which is more ideal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the second one contains state.

Personally, I would use the first one statically, like

```
class UserValidator{

     private UserValidator() { } // no constructor

     public static void Validate(Request request, Response response){
        // some validation logic on request
        // if fails, add the message to response.
     }

}
```

However, there is an advantage to storing the result - you can run it again and again without needing to actually run it.

```
class UserValidator {
    public static enum ValidatorState { NOT_RUN, PASSED, FAILED }
    private ValidatorState state = NOT_RUN;
    private final Request request;
    private final Response response;
    public UserValidator(Request request, Response response) {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
    }
    public ValidatorState validate() {
        if(state != NOT_RUN) return state;
        if(blah blah)
            state = PASSED;
        else
            state = FAILED;
        return state;
    }
}
```

To have a list of various validators, you will need some kind of interface to perform that.

```
public interface Validator {
    boolean validate(Request request, Response response);
}
```

Then you would create a static method library with all your validation. Note that these are made up examples, but contain some real-world-ish kind of logic.

```
public class ValidationLibrary {
    private ValidationLibrary() { }
    public boolean validateUsername(Request request, Response response) {
        String name = request.getProperty("username");
        if(name.length() < 3) return false;
        if(name.length() > 12) return false;
        if(name.equals(name.reverse()) return false; // who knows?
        return true;
    }
    public boolean validateSecurity(Request request, Response response) {
        // what page is the user trying to reach?
        SecurityRealm realm = SecurityRealm.realmForPage(request.getProperty("page"));
        String username = request.getProperty("name");
        return realm.allows(username);
    }
}
```

Later if you need multiple validators, you can simply do this

```
List<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>();
validators.add(new Validator(){ 
    public boolean validate(Request req, Response res) { ValidationLibrary.validateUsername(req,res); } 
});
validators.add(new Validator(){ 
    public boolean validate(Request req, Response res) { ValidationLibrary.validateSecurity(req,res); } 
});
```

Then when you get a request, you simply do this to validate it:

```
for(Validator v : validators) if(!v.validate(request,response)) return false;
```

Comment: well first one is not good, lets say if you want to make a composite validators right? you cant pass a static class to a collection or a method, unless you have a factory or whatsoever

Comment: First one is good because if i'm not storing the state I should not have an object. Objects with only behaviors are an antipattern and should be avoided. You can always make a Functor to serve as your closure if you need it, and this design allows you to if you need it, but you only need to do it if you need it.

Comment: well the drawback of static class is that you cant pass it to another method. and why wouldnt you store any state? state makes things easier to test no?

Comment: Not really. The state doesn't really need to persist for any particular length of time - typically only long enough to report the result of the test. Storing the results beyond is kind of a waste - your framework (JUnit, NUnit, etc) should be handling that for you.

Comment: If you need to make a collection of validators, you're best bet is to have an interface with a `validate` method. When you do this, you can always create an anonymous class to call the static method if you need to.

Comment: well that will be a problem because and interface can not have a static method. so if i dig into this more, it gets complicated. and for what really?

Comment: You misunderstand what I mean - allow me to create an example.